# Недокументированные свойства process в Node.js

Tags: node.js

Где можно посмотреть, хоть в исходниках хоть на где, про недокументированные свойства Process.* , знаю что есть например process._getActiveHandles() и process._getActiveRequests() , вот интересно где можно прочитать про другие возможности

Comment: используйте [поиск на github](https://github.com/nodejs/io.js/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=_getActiveHandles)

Comment: ну я бы хотел какое-то описание, так то можно просто выплюнуть в консоль process и всё узнать, но без описания мне многое не всовсем понятно , например что такое   _tickCallback:или _tickDomainCallback

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var key in process) {
  console.log(key);
}
```

Comment: хм , а зачем так сложно, простой console.log(process);  всё выводит , вот описание этих ф-ций заиметь бы

Comment: @vnn198, если сделать `console.log(key, process[key].toString())`, то можно увидеть код.

Comment: @vnn198, а использовать приватные методы вообще нехорошо.